# Angular images do not appear after binding

Tags: angular, image, binding

I have a project in which the images must be uploaded to server and then immediately shown. I manage to upload the images correctly in the folder assets/images. But then when i bind the src attribute of the image, this is not shown. To show the image I have to restart the application.

Here is the html:

```
<img *ngIf="product.imgPath!=''" src="{{product.imgPath}}" style="max-width:300px" />
```

When I check the address of the image it is correct, but the picture is not shown.

Comment: any error you are getting ?

Comment: No, no error. As I said the src attribute is correctly filled but the picture is not shown, I can see only a small icon that represents the image.

Comment: why is it not valid? When I restart the application the pictures are shown.

Answer (score 1):

The `assets` folder is usually for static assets. When in development mode , you need to restart `ng serve` after modifying the content of the `assets` folder.

I'd advise that you upload your assets somewhere else and that you serve them with a webserver (nginx or other)

Comment: How do I serve them with a web server, please explain. And where can I upload the pictures?

Comment: You add a rule to your nginx/apache/IIS webserver  so that the content of your image folder is accessible without going through `ng serve`

Comment: I am working locally in development with VS and IiS Express. There must be another solution to do this. I understand that the new static content is not recognized?

Comment: How do you reference the image path? It mist be something handled by IIS. If it's just 'http://localhost:4200/assets', then it will not work

Comment: i use a relative path:    "../assets/images/nameofimage.jpg"

Comment: it worked perfectly with another project made just in asp net core without angular. the images were shown immediately. Now I have to restart the application to see them, i think it is pretty unconvenient that angular treats static files this way

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind src like below

```
<img *ngIf="product.imgPath!=''" [src]="product.imgPath" style="max-width:300px" />
```